# How to do arithemtic operations with an alias in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, alias, arithmetic-expressions

I want to calculate with an alias in sqlite (Example is modified from http://www.sqlitetutorial.net):

if i do it like this, i get the error message "no such column: tracks_count"

```
SELECT albumid,
       title,
       (
           SELECT count(trackid) 
             FROM tracks
            WHERE tracks.AlbumId = albums.AlbumId
       )
       tracks_count, tracks_count * album_nr
  FROM albums
 ORDER BY tracks_count DESC;
```

if i do it like this, i get zero for the mulitplication

```
SELECT albumid,
       title,
       (
           SELECT count(trackid) 
             FROM tracks
            WHERE tracks.AlbumId = albums.AlbumId
       )
       tracks_count, "tracks_count" * album_nr
  FROM albums
 ORDER BY tracks_count DESC;
```

Table data for the example:

table albums

[image: albums]

table tracks

[image: tracks]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need a subquery here:

```
SELECT
    a.albumid,
    a.title,
    COUNT(t.albumid) AS tracks_count,
    COUNT(t.albumid) * a.album_nr AS other_count
FROM albums a
LEFT JOIN tracks t
    ON a.albumid = t.albumid
GROUP BY
    a.albumid,
    a.title;
```

If you wanted to make your current approach work, then the problem you are having is that you are referring to the `tracks_count` alias in the same select in which it was defined.  This isn't allowed, because the alias may not have even been computed yet.  But, I would recommend using the answer I gave above.